# Bottle filling without a rapid bottler

Tags: equipment, techniques, bottling

I'm about to bottle my first Coopers home brew and I don't have a rapid bottler. Can I pour it straight from the tap or will I have problems?

Comment: What is a rapid bottler?

Comment: AKA bottling wand / bottle filler.  My LHBS has a pic - http://www.westbrew.com.au/showProduct/Home+Brewing/Bottling+and+Sealing/510030

Comment: Sometimes I just use a pinchable-hose and siphon the beer into the bottles. I get the bottles close by and well below the source container. Pinch off the hose high enough that you can get the hose all the way down into the beer bottle without letting go of the pinch. About a foot of hose will be dangling below the pinch site. Prevent oxygen and turbulence- Dont let the hose hook around and point upward. When the hose touches near the bottle bottom, slowly release the beer until the bottle is full and pinched. Maybe a good clamp can help, but I just use my hands. This always works "in a pinch".

Answer (score 2):

The bottling wand that comes in the Cooper's kit is there to make bottling easier & doesn't add any special technique required for the process.  If you do pour straight from the tap, unless you're careful, you'll find it hard to fill the bottles to consistent / accurate levels, you will likely make a huge mess and you could waste precious beer.

I'd recommend holding out an extra day & visiting your local homebrew store to pick one up (they're under $10 where I live) but as long as you're careful, you could get away with bottling straight out of the tap.

For more info, have a read of ["How To Brew" - Section 1, Chapter 11](http://howtobrew.com/section1/chapter11.html) covers priming & bottling.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean a tap on your fermentor/bottling bucket and not a tap like from a kegging system.

The biggest problem is getting too much air/oxygen into the beer.  You can fill that way, but the beer will potentially stale faster because of the oxygen pick up.  At least get a piece of tubing that will reach from the "tap" to the bottom of the bottle.  Fill slowly and when you pull the bottle off the tubing you should have about the right amount of head space.